# Estimating the mutual information in high dimension when all but one variable are iid

Tags: high-dimensional, mutual-information, function, iid

I have a function $f(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})$ where $n$ is large and I would like to estimate the mutual information between the random variable $f(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})$ and the independent and identically distributed (iid) random variables $X_{1},\dots,X_{n}$ (so $I(f(X_{1},\dots,X_{n});X_{1},\dots,X_{n})$), given a large number of samples.

I am vaguely aware that a number of methods exist for estimating the mutual information in high dimension but given that all but one of the random variables are iid in this case, I'm hoping that the calculation simplifies dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

Ah....actually it seems to be extremely (read embarrassingly) simple. It seems I can just write
$$
I(f(X_{1},\dots,X_{n};X_{1},\dots,X_{n}) \equiv H(f(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}))-H(f(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})|X_{1},\dots,X_{n}) \\= H(f(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}))
$$
(since $f(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})$ is a deterministic function).